# Lazyload and filter issue - images below fold not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm struggling with the jquery Lazyload script when I combine this with a simple jquery filter. At first glance it all seems to work nicely, however when i combine this with filtering I'm runnign into trouble. In essence, when I apply the filter, the images which were originally positioned below the fold (i.e. those which had not yet been scrolled down to) are not shown, only the placeholder and there is no way (that I can see) to change this.

Can someone please help? I'm guessing that it's something relatively straightforward. You can see the issue here: http://megmackayphoto.com/port... and then applying the filters on the left hand side before scrolling.

I've added an example fiddle on this here too: http://jsfiddle.net/iameuanmackay/hybf13h1/

Code:

```
                <ul id="filter">
                    <li style="list-style-type: none" class="all"><a href="#">all</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li style="list-style-type: none" class="people"><a href="#people">people</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li style="list-style-type: none" class="things"><a href="#things">things</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end affix -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
        <div id="visible-container">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-2 col-md-10 col-lg-7 col-lg-push-3" style="padding-left:5px">
                <ul id="portfolio">
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people1.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/140220_MabelFlwrCrwn_056.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people1.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/140220_MabelFlwrCrwn_129.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people2.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/131017_FlowerWall_215.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people2.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/131017_FlowerWall_233.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people3.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/130907_3DayPortraits_151.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people3.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/130907_3DayPortraits_140.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="things"><a href="portfolio/things4.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/things/130712_PeachWedding_147.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="things"><a href="portfolio/things4.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/things/130712_PeachWedding_065.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people4.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/130331_ScotlandEaster_090.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people4.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/130331_ScotlandEaster_095.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people5.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/120830_SeattlePics_411.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people5.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/130813_ScotlandTrip_110.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people6.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/140318_KirstyGrieve_235.jpg"  width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people6.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/140318_KirstyGrieve_391.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people7.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/260913_HelenPatrick_208b.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="people"><a href="portfolio/people7.html"><img class="lazy" data-original="http://megmackayphoto.com/lib/img/thumbs/people/260913_HelenPatrick_162.jpg" width="185" height="185"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the lazyload trigger is: 
    $(function () {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload()
    threshold: 100;
    effect: "scrollstop";
    });

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact, that lazyload only looks for specific events (i.e.: scroll, scrollstop) to detect whether images are in view.

Additionally jquery lazyload has some disadvantages with runtime performance and leaks memory with AJAX websites/SPAs.

I would suggest to use https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes, which introduces a new era of "lazyloader" by detecting any visibility changes to current in document images as also any future images without the need of any JS configuration or need to call any JS functions. Additionally I have put a lot of energy to make it as runtime-, network- and memory- efficient as possible.

There is also a wordpress plugin in the works https://github.com/aFarkas/wp-lazysizes. It is currently alpha/beta but should work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @alexanderfarkas i actually came across lazysizes today - will investigate this route and let you know how i get on.